# Installation Error --  Class 'DateTime' not found

Tags: sugarcrm

I got this error when I was installing the SugarCRM  on the server：

> > Fatal error: Class 'DateTime' not found in /home/fuyinshidai/CRM/include/SugarDateTime.php on line 43
> >
> > Fatal error: Class 'DateTime' not found in /home/fuyinshidai/CRM/include/TimeDate.php on line 1353

But it didn't happen during local installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version and flavor of Sugar is this for? And which version of PHP are you using?

Sugar only supports 5.2.1 and later.

Comment: Thanks PHP version 5.16 is the very low

Comment: Sugar only supports 5.2.1 and later.

Comment: @jmertic - This does raise the issue of graceful failure and dependency checking.  In fact, I think the install checks for the PHP version, so this may be a case where the filesystem was moved post-install.  Is there a standard way to do an environment check without huge overhead? Maybe if local IP changes, re-run dependency check?

Comment: It does PHP version checking during install and upgrade. We could do it more often at the cost of increased overhead for the small chance someone is doing what you are doing. Not sure if there's value in that IMHO.